What is the nature of the bonds in BaO2 (Ionic or covalent)?
My study material mentions that BaO2 has both covalent and ionic bonds, but doesn't provide any explanation regarding this.

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

It is what we call "ionic peroxide".

$\ce{BaO2}$ or Barium Peroxide consists of $\ce{Ba^2+}$ cation and $\ce{O2^2-}$ anion (or peroxide anion)
The ionic bond exists between the ions ($\ce{Ba^2+}$ and $\ce{O2^2-}$)
Whereas the covalent bond exists within the peroxide ion itself
You might want to visit this site and understand the lattice.

In a crystalline lattice it is not a good picture that ionic "bonds" occur between pairs of atoms - each ion interacts with every single other atom in the whole of the lattice, and A bonds to B picture is just not appropriate. Hence I suggest you at least drop the picture from the answer above.

I agree with you @IanBush, but the OP mentions about the structure of $\ce{BaO2}$ alone and I thought that a formula unit would suffice to answer his question. I will do as u mentioned
